# How to show first b-collapse used it with v-for?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue

I want to show only first b-collapse on first render.

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in items">
  <b-button v-b-toggle="`collapse-${ item.id }`" class="m-1">{{ item.name }}</b-button>
  <b-collapse :visible="index === 0" :id="`collapse-${ item.id }`">
    <b-card>{{ item.description }}</b-card>
  </b-collapse>
</div>
```

How to fix it?

Comment: what issue you are facing ?

Comment: I added an answer. Hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `:visible`, You can try below mentioned any of the solution **:**

```
<b-collapse v-show="index === 0" :id="`collapse-${ item.id }`">
  <b-card>{{ item.description }}</b-card>
</b-collapse>
```

---- OR ----

```
<b-collapse :style="{visibility: (index === 0) ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}" :id="`collapse-${ item.id }`">
  <b-card>{{ item.description }}</b-card>
</b-collapse>
```